# What is the difference between Kinto and Cliquet?

Tags: python, pyramid, cornice, kinto

Why is [Kinto](http://kinto.readthedocs.org/) using [Cliquet](http://cliquet.readthedocs.org/) and what is the difference between the two ?

---

**Disclaimer**: *I am one of the authors of both tools. Since this is frequently asked question, I thought it would be relevant to share a proper answer here :)*

Answer (score 4):

At Mozilla Services we regularly implement and deploy micro-services.

Since most services share the same production requirements (in terms of monitoring, REST protocols etc.), we decided to develop and package a reusable toolkit using [Cornice](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/).

Kinto is one of those services. It uses Cliquet as one of its core libraries.

The Kinto HTTP API is made of several REST endpoints, that all share a set of common properties (filtrable, sortable etc.). The common code base for those REST resources is implemented as a reusable class in *Cliquet*.

We really like the name *Cliquet*. However, given the confusion of its scope, we will probably (some day) split it into two packages, called like *cornice-mozprod* and *cornice-crud*.

Comment: One question I would have then, if I'm interested in writing a basic REST service should I use vanilla Cornice or go with Cliquet?

Comment: If this REST service has a CRUD, then Cliquet will be a real time-saver! Everything about interacting with a storage backend is taken care of, you just have to focus on your data schema.

Comment: @PeterTirrell, it depends what you call "basic", actually. Cliquet comes with a bunch of opinions about what a REST endpoint should be and how it should behave. I would recommend using Cliquet to save re-doing a bunch of things but for some very simple use cases it doesn't make sense and Cornice is a better fit.

Comment: Note that since `Kinto 3.0`, `Cliquet` have been merged into Kinto code base and renamed `kinto.core`. You can still use kinto.core to achieve what was doable with Cliquet but it makes it easier to grasp for new comers.

Answer (score 0):

Kinto and Cliquet have now be merged together, and cliquet is no longer a thing.

See all the nifty details at https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/kinto/2016-May/000119.html